# React Native images won't display on certain mobile devices

Tags: android, react-native

I've been developing a mobile app using React Native and deploying it onto a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge for testing purposes via Expo.  So far, everything has worked fine and all of the images I'm using have displayed correctly.

However, when I've tried to deploy it onto other devices, certain images have failed to display.  On the Huawei MediaPad, the header image (encased in an `<Image>` tag) fails to display and on the Samsung Galaxy S8 and the OnePlus 6, the background image (encased in an `<ImageBackground>` tag) fails to display.

I've attempted running a compiled APK file of the app, believing that these issues could be related to streaming the images over Wi-Fi, but to no avail.  Interestingly though, the background image displayed fine across all devices until I swapped it out for a new image (as the predecessor was merely a placeholder).  Both images are 4K (3840 x 2160), with the only difference being the storage size of the image.  As a debugging measure, I compressed the new image in Photoshop with the strongest setting but, again, to no avail.

Below is the code I am using to render the two Images (not a complete paste of course, but I'm happy to do so on request):

```
<ImageBackground
        source={require('./../../assets/images/bg_portrait_dots.png')}
        style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'absolute'}}
        >
            <View style={styles.parentView}>
                <View style={styles.elementSpacer}>
                    <Image
                        source={require('./../../assets/images/iview_learning_logo.png')}
                        style={styles.headerImage}
                    />
                </View>
```

Below are the Stylesheet arguments which control the elements listed above:

```
parentView: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
headerImage: {
    width: null,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: 120,
    position: 'relative',
},
elementSpacer: {
    flex: 1,
},
```